# Export shared Outlook calendar to Excel

Tags: excel, csv, outlook, calendar

I have "Reviewer" access to a shared (Exchange) calendar, but when I go through the process to manually export to CSV I am only able to view/select my *personal* calendar to download.
Do I have the appropriate permissions? Is there a solution I'm missing or some manual step I can take that would make one of the following solutions work?

**What I've tried:**

1. The obvious: File > Open & Export > etc. etc. Instructions here: http://www.everydayanalytics.ca/2013/11/how-to-export-your-outlook-inbox-to-csv.html
2. Changing to list view then copying and pasting into Excel. This is the closest solution I can find, but tedious and doesn't include all of the fields I would've expected.
3. Trying to import calendar directly from Access. Same problem occurs--I can only select my personal calendar, not the shared one.

**Parameters & Additional Info:**

- Most of the events I need are all-day events, rather than time-specific. Some are repeating.
- The solution must not involve downloading a new program. It needs to work from various computers, and the person who will be completing the task won't have permissions to download new programs.
- My *preference* is for a manual solution rather than VBA, as I'll be passing this task on to a beginner. But if VB is the only option,
  I'll take it.
- At minimum I need the following fields: Subject, Date
  Created, Start, End, and Category.
- I'm using Office 2013 on a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per a response I received on Microsoft's community forum, "It's nothing you are doing. Owner permissions aren't enough - you can't share or export calendars that are not in an account in your profile. You'd need to add the mailbox to your profile **using the username and password**. Or use an external utility.

Or use a list view, then select all, copy and paste into Excel- this will work fine with the fields you need (the body field doesn't copy and paste well.)"

Answer (score 1):

I also have Reviewer access to a shared calendar, so I just tested this with mine, and it appears to work. The only issue is my shared calendar has no events, but it should work.

What I did:

1. Go to my calendars in Outlook and change the view to list view, as you have done before.
2. I right clicked on my shared calendar and clicked "Copy Calendar"
3. From there, I had created a folder to copy the shared calendar to, that was under my personal account. (You should be able to paste it anywhere under your exchange account.)
4. Once the shared calendar was under my personal account, I could go into File > Open & Export > etc. as you already did, and I could select the shared calendar that was copied into my personal account to export as a csv.

I am working out of Office 2016, but I think it should follow mostly the same. **Edit:** I had a coworker who is still on Office 2013 try this and it worked for him.

Comment: This looks so promising! ...but i am getting a "The Operation Failed" error after selecting a folder to paste the copied one into.

Comment: Did you create a new folder to put it into, or did you try pasting into an already created folder?

Comment: You can also try pasting to your personal calendar, it will just create a sub-folder for the shared one. Just make sure you are trying to paste into your personal account folders, because when you choose "Copy Folder" it will initially show you the shared account, and you need to scroll up to yours.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both--creating a new folder (set to contain calendar items) within my personal account and as a sub-folder of my existing calendar. No dice.

Comment: Not sure why I was down-voted, as this is a viable solution. I am not sure why it will not work for you, but as I edited above, I had a coworker on Office 2013 try this and it worked just fine for him.

Comment: I'm not sure why my question was downvoted, nor your response. It's a good suggestion. Still not working for me, however.